# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ehp' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I've been writing a shitty text-based game for the first time using python, and I've encountered a problem whilst making a function for a battle. It would be called upon each time you encounter an enemy, and the variables will be defined before each fight.

The problem I'm having is that my variable, 'ehp', is being referenced before the assignment of the variable. (Stands for Enemy Health Points). My code is listed below and I would like some help as to what to change to my code to prevent the error code that I'm getting with my program.

```
import random

hp = int(20)
ehp = int(10)
def fight():
    print("You have encountered",(enemy))
    if speed >= espeed:
        first = "c"
    for x in range(100):
        if ehp <= 0:
            print("You have won!")
            break
        elif hp <= 0:
            print("You have died!")
            break
        else:
            print("1: Light Attack")
            print("2: Heavy Attack")
            print("3: Dodge")
            attack = input("1/2/3: ")
            if attack == "1":
                print("You have used, Light Attack!")
                lightdam = (random.randint(0,damage/2))
                print("You have inflicted,",edam,"to",enemy)
                ehp = ehp - (random.randint(0,damage/2))
                print("Enemy Health:",ehp)
                print(character,"Health:",hp)
                print(enemy,"Has used attack!")
                eattack = (random.randint(0,edam/2))
                print(enemy,"Has inflicted",eattack,"damage!")
                hp = hp - eattack
                print("Enemy Health:",ehp)
                print(character,"Health:",hp)
            elif attack == "2":
                print("You have used, Heavy Attack!")
                heavydam = (random.randint(0,damage))
                print("You have inflicted,",heavydam,"to",enemy)
                ehp = ehp - (random.randint(0,damage))
                print("Enemy Health:",ehp)
                print(character,"Health:",hp)
                print(enemy,"Has used attack!")
                eattack = (random.randint(0,edam))
                print(enemy,"Has inflicted",eattack,"damage!")
                hp = hp - eattack
                print("Enemy Health:",ehp)
                print(character,"Health:",hp)

print("Welcome to the tales of Iryophia, please enter your characters name.")
character = input("Character name: ")
print("Garnier the Honorable:")
print("Welcome to the city of Iryophia, do you remember how you got here?")
y0 = input("Y/N: ")
for x in range(6):
    if y0 == "N":
        print("Garnier the Honorable:")
        print("Well",character,", all I can remember is a certain man entering a neighbouring town, and well, I'm not sure how to put this, but, you were killed.")
        print("I understand how crazy this may sound but you were brought back to life. You would have lost all of your memory, but, you are alive!")
        print("Do you remember the name of the man who killed you?")
        nemesis = input("Nemesis: ")
        print("Garnier the Honorable:")
        print("Ah yes, I remember now,",nemesis,"was his name.")
        break
    if y0 == "Y":
        print("Garnier the Honorable:")
        print("Okay, well the man that attacked you, what was his name?")
        nemesis = input("Nemesis: ")
        print("Garnier the Honorable:")
        print("Ah yes, I remember now,",nemesis,"was his name.")
        break

print("Come back with me to my home.")
print("")
print("Garnier the Honorable:")
print("I have a bow, an axe, or a sword for you. Which one do you pick?")
weapon = input("Bow/Axe/Sword: ")
for x in range(6):
    if weapon == "Bow":
        damage = int(3)
        speed = int(5)
        break
    if weapon == "Axe":
        damage = int(7)
        speed = int(3)
        break
    if weapon == "Sword":
        damage = int(5)
        speed = (4)
        break
print("You have collected:",weapon+"!")
print("Damage:",damage)
print("Speed:",(speed))

print("Garnier the Honorable:")
print("Would you like to have a practice fight?")
fight0 = input("Y/N: ")
for x in range(6):
    if fight0 == "Y":
        ehp = int(10)
        enemy = "Garnier the Honorable"
        espeed = int(3)
        edam = int(4)
        fight()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Examine these two code lines in `fight()` (at *least* these two, though there may be others):

```
ehp = ehp - (random.randint(0,damage/2))
hp = hp - eattack
```

For variables not *explicitly* marked as global, Python makes some assumptions:

- if you only *use* the variable, it will follow the scope up through different levels until it finds a matching name; and
- if you set or change it *anywhere* in a function, it's considered a local variable *everywhere* in the function.

Hence a simple fix would be to explicitly mark it global in the function:

```
def fight():
    global ehp
    global hp
    print("You have encountered",(enemy))
    :
    and so on
```

A *better* fix would probably involve not using globals at all :-)

---

You should probably also review your hit-point processing, which contains such things as:

```
heavydam = (random.randint(0,damage))
print("You have inflicted,",heavydam,"to",enemy)
ehp = ehp - (random.randint(0,damage))
```

Telling the player they've inflicted some amount of damage then subtracting a totally *different* number of hit points is likely to have players scratching their heads trying to figure out how things work :-)